# Sum of bitwise OR of max and min element of every subsets of given array

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Given an array I have to find the sum of all the bitwise OR of the maximum and the minimum element of all possible subset of the given array whose size is greater than or equal to 2.
Eg- [1,3,5]
Subset with size >=2 are {1,3}{1,5}{3,5}{1,3,5}

{1,3}-biwise OR of the max and min element in this subset=3

{1,5}-biwise OR of the max and min element in this subset=5

{3,5}-biwise OR of the max and min element in this subset=7

{1,3,5}-biwise OR of the max and min element in this subset=5

So total sum is 3+5+7+5=20.

I tried to make modifications with Sum of bitwise OR of all possible subsets of given set but unable to draw a logic.

Note: The size of the array is of order 10^5.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here.

Comment: I have to write a program which fulfils the logic. But as order of array is very large, traversing each set to find min and max will be of order 2^n which is huge. I want to know if there is any other algo

Comment: What is the restriction on the size of subset?

Comment: This is the question from the currently ongoing competition in one of the online judge!!

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array. Loop though all pairs of elements from the set. Any subset that have these elements as min and max will give the same contribution. The number of such subset can be calculated by the index of the elements since the array is sorted. You may then calculate the combined contribution of these subset as the bitwise OR times number of subset.

Comment: Loop though all pairs is already O(n^2) which will be too much for n = 10^5

Comment: 10^10 isn't that much for modern computers. I think that should be doable in a lunch break.

Comment: Can it be reduced to O(nlog) solution?

Comment: @Shewta can you link original problem? The solution for this can be a number with 100000 digits, seems unlikely you have to answer this

Comment: @juvian..this was just verbally asked to me, however it was mentioned that we have to mod the result by 10^9+7

Comment: @juvian..also the elements of the array is between 1 to 1000 and not more.

Comment: @Shewta well that changes things drastically... if you have repeated elements would you repeat subsets or only consider unique ones? like, if input was [1, 1, 1] would subsets be [{1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}] or [{1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}] ?

Comment: @juvian subsets would be repeated..the later one in your example will be valid.

Comment: So only 1000 possible different numbers. Then I would try to loop over all pairs of possible values. For each pair calculate the number of subset that has these numbers as min and max. That should be significant faster.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode considering all numbers go from 1 to 1000:

```
int count[1001];
int accumulated[1001];

for each element in array:
    count[element]++;

diff_nums = []

for i = 1 to 1000:
    accumulated[i] = accumulated[i - 1] + count[i];
    if (count[i] > 0):
        diff_nums.push(i);

result = 0;

for i = 0 to diff_nums.size():
    i_el = diff_nums[i]
    result += i * (2^(count[i_el]) - count[i_el] - 1)         
    for j = i + 1 to diff_nums.size():
        j_el = diff_nums[j]
        numbers_between_i_and_j = accumulated[j_el - 1] - accumulated[i_el]
        amount_of_subsets_between_i_and_j = 2^(numbers_between_i_and_j)
        amount_of_subsets_with_at_least_1_i = (2^count[i_el] - 1)
        amount_of_subsets_with_at_least_1_j = (2^count[j_el] - 1)

        result += (i_el OR j_el) * amount_of_subsets_between_i_and_j * amount_of_subsets_with_at_least_1_i * amount_of_subsets_with_at_least_1_j
```

Being D the amount of unique numbers in N, the complexity of this is:

O(D^2 log n) assuming we do log n exponentiation with modulo

Comment: Brilliant! This solution is amazing! I just don't get one thing though. `result += i * (2^(count[i_el]) - count[i_el] - 1)` => This will always add `i/2` to the `result`? And why do we need to this?

Comment: @Raghav in the second loop we are considering all cases of subsets with diff_nums[i] as min and diff_nums[j] as max. However, we are not considering the cases where a subset is only made of diff_nums[i]. That line takes care of those cases. The amount of subsets using same number will be 2^(amount of that number). Then we substract 1 because of the empty subset and we also substract the amount of that number because we do not consider subsets with only 1 element.

Comment: Got it captain. Thanks!